# Cannot get onto Apple Developer Forums

Tags: development, developer-program

Every time I attempt to log on to the apple developer forums it tells me I need to create a new user account (even though I already have one), and when I try to sign up it gives me an error:
[image]

Anyone else have this issue and/or know how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a different browser and/or Incognito/Private mode? Just in case it is a problem with a cached file/cookie/whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AlistairMcMillan but I tried in a different browser with the same result.

Comment: So you go to https://forums.developer.apple.com/welcome and click "Log In" in the top left corner and you end up back at the "Create a New User Account" page?

Comment: Yes. I tried with my personal account, and it worked fine. However, when I use my developer account (which was signed up on the old forums) it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally after one year of effort one of the kind apple engineer replied to my ticket and the issue resolved and closed now. Please find below response from apple just in case any one is looking for it -

> Please note that there is an issue with non-standard email domains. We kindly ask you to create a new Apple ID with .com domain, and try to access the Forums with that. You don’t need to have an active paid membership to access the Forums.

Answer (score 2):

From time to time I have had this "create account" page appear for what seems like no reason.  In my case, there was a reason.

You may have already been logged in to Apple's single sign-on with an Apple ID that hasn't yet been set up for use with the developer forums.  When this occurs, the forums site picks up the login, notices that the logged-in Apple ID is not "forums ready", and forwards you to the "create account" page.

To get past this, you can go to developer.apple.com's "Member Center" to sort out your login, then return to the forums web site.

Comment: Yes - browsing in a private window or incognito window to make sure no cookies are set is a nice way to test things. Sometimes the "sign out" button doesn't clear what needs to be cleared.